# Лучше(,) чем; хуже(,) чем

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Подскажите, нужна ли здесь запятая:

*У них свои рецепты для крабовых пирожных, крабов в соусе и кремового супа из крабов — лучше(,) чем в ресторанах Кубы.*

Answer (score 1):

В сравнительном выражении «лучше чем» запятая нужна перед «чем». Это союзное слово часто присоединяет сравнение, будь то оборот или сравнительное придаточное. Запятая нужна в обоих случаях.

*Я готовлю лучше, чем моя сестра.
Он выступил лучше, чем обычно выступают спортсмены его возраста.*

Answer (score -1):

Да, запятая нужна. Это сравнительный оборот.
Обороты, присоединяемые союзом «чем», выделяются запятыми, если в предложении имеются два сравниваемых понятия.